# How to automatically accept all warnings/suggestions changes with resharper

Tags: resharper

I am very new to Resharper and trying to implement all the suggestion it gives. Can I do it automatically? I have tried code cleanup. but that wont do all of them. Also I need to remove all commented code. How can I do it? Also I am running it with a silverlight application. Is there any chance of breaking something if I auto accept the suggestions?

Comment: YOU DON'T WANT TO DO THAT!! 
Yes there are chances that you will break something.

Comment: I agree. But at least I might need to do some cleanups automatically like removing all commented code.

Comment: While 99% of the time you don't want to do this, there are definitely some cases where this makes perfect sense. Right now I have generated code from a tool that doesn't remotely conform to my coding standards. I'll be maintaining the code by hand now that the initial generation is done. Why shouldn't I be able to let Resharper clean it all up?

Answer (score 5):

It may be more work, but you should apply any cleanup operation "manually" so that you know what has been changed in your code, can learn from those changes, and can be sure that all the changes are correct. Code Analysis tools offer you suggestions, but they are never 100% correct - sometimes you need to do a bit of the programming yourself ;-)

Don't think of it as a chore. Think of it as a (tedious and repetitive) way of learning a better coding style. THe more often you accept a specific change, the more strongly you will remember the "better" way to write similar code the next time.

Comment: +1 - ditto. I did the same sort of manual cleanup with FxCop violations and learned a lot from that. Once it's clean, keep it clean - keep R# green, turn on Warnings as Errors, and consider running FxCop under Continuous Integration.

Comment: definitely  a good idea to do this manually for each fix I have seen several bugs creep into code when resharper made suggestions. Resharper is a fantastic tool but its just a tool and sometimes it doesn't get the context quite right and changes code in ways you cannot perceive. This gets better version to version.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it by code [cleanup](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way to do this.

Even if there were, ReSharper will often give you a choice of actions to take - which would be accepted if this were done automatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you can find examples that you think ReSharper should cater for automatically, you might like to request the feature on their Jira site and post the link here for others to vote on:

http://www.jetbrains.net/jira/browse/RSRP